# Report generation from OpenLayers

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers

Can you suggest how a JasperReport can be generated by an user accessing an point (say a wireless tower in map) on a active layer done in OpenLayers 3. Here the architecture uses OpenLayers 3 and is linked with GeoServer and PostGIS.

The Jasper report that needs to be launched for the selected wireless tower or point, needs to pick some spatial coordinates (location, intersections etc) and non-spatial information/data (installation date of tower, some runtime statistics info of tower etc) from PostGIS database, for the respective telecom tower.

Comment: FYI users JasperReport http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports